# height of AVL-esque tree?

Tags: tree

So we know that the height of an AVL tree is O(log n), but what about a similar tree, but instead of the height difference being -1 to 1, it differed from -2 to 2? how would I prove the height of such a tree?

Comment: Maximum height, or average height? Either way I suspect it's the sane order, just a different constant multiplier

Comment: its for maximum height

Comment: I'd try to prove it by deriving a formula for the minimum number of nodes N in a tree of height H. By definition, this is a worst-case height, so if you find that N is based on exp(H), then H is log(N).